# What does the quote "Hasta lasagna" mean in Mission Impossible I?

Tags: dialogue, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-1996

Around min 10 into the movie, Jack Harmon tells Ethan not to chew the explosive gum by saying:
"Hasta lasagna don't get any on ya"
What does this mean?
Why does he uses "hasta lasagna"?

Comment: It might be just a joke: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100626172224AAWUrZy

Comment: Thanks mattiav27, that was my guess too, I just never heard this expression. I am a native spansih and I just watched the original dialogue (in Spain, it was translated as: "Hasta lasagna, métele caña" - So the second part would be sort of "get it going" which didn´t make any sense)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jack's basically warning him that's it's dangerous with a playful **schoolyard phrase.** Originally, this is supposed to be a play on Spanish goodbye phrases *Hasta la vista*, *Hasta luego* and *Hasta manana* ('Goodbye', 'till we meet again' and 'until tomorrow') with the childish twist of turning it into a food item and tacking a rhyme on in the end. It's similar to many other known childhood phrases, some of which are also about food and all of which are equally nonsensical, like:

> "See you later, Alligator!"
>
> "In a while, Crocodile!"
>
> "What's shakin', Bacon?"
>
> "Okey dokey, Artichokey!"
>
> “Guess what? Chicken butt!”

So the 'lasagna' part is meaningless, it just sounds like a combination of La vista\Luego and Manana, or is simply a bastardization of one of them.

*[Note that it's a double meaning, BTW: Jack tells Ethan it'll be the end of him (with the 'goodbye' part) and also to be careful around it ('don't get any on ya'). So he's being playful **and** instructive! ;)]*

Comment: Besides that, he might very well also play with the fact that anyone chewing that bubble gum for too long will pretty much become, well, lasagna.